# How to write in a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to check if a cell in one sheet has a certain value, and if that's the case write a text string in another cell in another sheet.

Afterwards I would like to call the same sub in some range in the first sheet and apply it to the corresponding range in the other sheet. The ranges don’t have them same location, only the same size.

Here is an example:
[image]

The first binary matrix is in the first sheet. (The location could as an example be in A1:B2).
The second matrix is made based on the first matrix (The location could as an example be in A1:B2).

This is my idea so far (notice, it isn't working yet)

```
Sub Convert(SomeCell, AnotherCell)
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(SomeCell).Value > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(AnotherCell).Value = "String"
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I'm searching for the corresponding VBA code for this IF statement formula

```
= IF(Sheet1!A1>0;"String";"")
```

Which then can be dragged in some range.

Comment: Your code snippet works if called correctly (so I don't know what you mean by "(notice, it isn't working yet)"), but why do you want to use a sub rather than a function? Why do you want to use VBA at all here?

Comment: It was a guess, I assumed it didn't work, since I couldn't get it to work. So I may have called it wrongly. I'm trying to avoid having formula in the final table, because I want to manually change it, then the formulas would be overwrote. Before starting this task next time I have to start with formulas in all cell from scratch. And also the final table depends on several other tables, it would be a quite long formula, so better to hide it in a module if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you an idea:

```
Sub Convert(Source As Range, Target As Range, Replace As Variant)
    'Takes a binary matrix in source range and fills in target range
    'with value Replace taking the place of 1
    'assumes equal sized ranges
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Source.Columns.Count
            If Source.Cells(i, j).Value = 1 Then Target.Cells(i, j).Value = Replace
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Called like:

```
Sub test()
    Convert Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2"), Sheets(2).Range("A1:B2"), "String"
End Sub
```

There are probably better ways to do it, but this will give you a way to represent a binary matrix in one sheet with a string matrix in another (if that is what you were trying to do). Note that unexpected results could occur if the source and target range overlap.